# avoiding group by clause while using aggregate function in sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have this SQL query where I am using an aggregate function, but I dont want to use `group by` clause as it will mess up my data. This is the first query where I have to use lots of `group by` for one aggregate function.

```
 select ti.task_name,cast(ti.start_date As VARCHAR),cast(th.created_date As VARCHAR),sum(th.previous_completed) as total,
ld.level_data,pi.project_code_1,pi.project_code_2
 from task_history th
left join task_information ti on ti.id =th.task_id
 left join project_information pi on ti.project_id = pi.id
 left join lookup_data ld on ti.activity=ld.id
where cast((th.created_date)as date) between '2021-06-28' and  '2021-06-29'  and ti.employee_id='092cdd13-5f30-4980-93d0-8246239728fd'
group by ti.employee_id,ti.task_name,ti.start_date,ld.level_data,th.created_date,pi.project_code_1,pi.project_code_2
```

and i am getting this result:

```
 attend hotline calls        | 2021-06-28 | 2021-06-28 05:22:03.310768 |     0 | Sales monitoring
          |                |
 attend hotline calls        | 2021-06-28 | 2021-06-28 16:38:42.676874 |     3 | Sales monitoring
```

It was supposed to sum into 1 column.

This is the query where I have avoided all the column names to avoid duplicate result:

```
select ti.task_name,sum(th.previous_completed) as total
 from task_history th
left join task_information ti on ti.id =th.task_id
 left join project_information pi on ti.project_id = pi.id
 left join lookup_data ld on ti.activity=ld.id
where cast((th.created_date)as date) between '2021-06-28' and  '2021-06-29'  and ti.employee_id='092cdd13-5f30-4980-93d0-8246239728fd'
group by ti.task_name
```

I am getting this result:

```
 attend hotline calls        |     3
```

The first result shows one extra column and the second result is as expected but I also want to include the column of the first result.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean "it will mess up by data"?  Please provide sample data, desired results, and a very clear explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: updated the question.For one aggregate function i have to use all of the coumn name in group by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that `th.created_date` is a timestamp which you are using as as one of your `GROUP BY` columns. The time is different on each record so there is no grouping on that column.

I'm not certain why you need to cast dates as Character Varying, but in any case if you cast to date first (e.g. th.created_date::DATE) as both the column you select and in `GROUP BY`. Then it will give you the sum for each date (rather than for each microsecond).

Answer (score 0):

You can use *window* function :

```
select ti.activity, ld.level_data, 
       sum(th.previous_completed) over (partition by ti.activity,ld.level_data) as total
from task_history th left join 
     task_information ti 
     on ti.id =th.task_id left join 
     lookup_data ld 
     on ti.activity=ld.id
```